# What is $(.some-class:#some-hash) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm studying [this article](http://happyworm.com/blog/2010/08/23/the-future-of-web-apps-single-page-applications/), the details of which are irrelevant to this question, which is about jQuery syntax.

In the example at the link above, there's the following piece of JavaScript

```js
$(function() {
  // ...
  var tabPostFix = 'Tab';
  var hash = location.hash;
  if (hash.length > 0) {
    // ...
    var idx = $('.tabPage').index($(".tabPage:"+hash+tabPostFix));
    var thisTab = $('.tab:eq('+idx+')');
    // ...
  }
  // ...
});
```

where `tabPage` and `tab` are classes in HTML file.

Despite I was under the impression that the "dollar syntax" of jQuery used CSS syntax, I eventually found that the syntax [`$('.tab:eq(some-number)')` is indeed valid jQuery syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_eq.asp), even though it isn't CSS syntax, is it?

On the other hand, I haven't found what `$('whatever:#some-hash')`. Given the example, I think the `.index` method is trying to pick the HTML element with class `tabPage` and `id` attribute the result of `hash+tabPostFix` (well, without the leading `#`), but I don't get the significance of the `:` right after `tabPage`.

Comment: `$('whatever:#some-hash')` will produce an error; it's not a valid selector.

Comment: are you aware that the article is from 2010? 11 years ago ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes I knew. But despite the errors that might affect it, do you think the stuff out shows is not needed anymore? Is so, what it's a modern corresponding strategy?

Comment: jQuery uses mostly css selectors but also has pseudo selectors. See [jQuery Selector extensions docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/jquery-selector-extensions/). It is also possible to create your own pseudo selectors by extending `$.expr` yourself

Comment: @Spectric, I know that's a pseudo class in CSS and I had understood that jQuery makes use of it, but I thought that followed by `#some-hash` could mean something other than a psudo-class, or simply a non-CSS pseudo-class. Now, based on your first comment, the problem is that the example is bugged. Probably I just need to remove that `:` so I'd get a valid `.some-class#some-id` CSS selector.